# Is MPI_Bsend_init/MPI_Start best asynchronous buffered communication.

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Is MPI_Bsend_init/MPI_Start best asynchronous buffered communication. Can you guys think of better way to communicate data between processors. Pseudo-Code for N Processing nodes

```
   MPI_Recv(request[i]) -- Recv data

   for(i=0;i<N;i++) MPI_Bsend_init(request[i]) -- Setup request

   MPI_Start(request[i]) -- Send data
```

Comment: If you want (a) persistant communication requests and (b) buffered communication, that this is a perfectly decent way to do it.  But I haven't found that persistant communications in practice give any significant performance benefit, and buffered sends have their own problems, as enumerated by this OpenMPI developer - http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/top-10-reasons-why-buffered-sends-are-evil/ .

Comment: @JonathanDursi Thanks a lot for information. I'm having issues with MPI_Bsend as-well. Do you suggest just using MPI_Isend instead.

Answer (score 1):

Bsend is the wrong function here from a performance standpoint.  There is little to no advantage of Bsend, as the eager protocol used by essentially all implementations today, is buffered on the receiver side automatically for small messages, which is where Bsend would be viable.

In any case, persistent send - as you are using - is already nonblocking, so there is no such thing as Isent_init.  See e.g. http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node51.html:

> The call is local, with similar semantics to the nonblocking
>   communication operations described in section Nonblocking
>   communication . That is, a call to MPI_START with a request created by
>   MPI_SEND_INIT starts a communication in the same manner as a call to
>   MPI_ISEND...

And my colleagues have surprised me with confirmation that persistent Send-Recv does provide efficiency gains on modern InfiniBand clusters.  I can only assume this is because IB page registration is done up-front.